# .htaccess - Convert PHP GET to URL Path but keep GET in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

My Goal was to redirect a URL like  `http://example.com/c/themeforest/wordpress` to the PHP `http://example.com/?params=c/themeforest/wordpress`.

To achieve this, I used a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

But now I have to also be able to redirect URLs like `http://example.com/c/themeforest/wordpress?p=2`
to `http://example.com/?params=c/themeforest/wordpress&p=2` for multiple Pages.

The Page Number has to be sent in a seperate PHP GET Variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the QSA (query string append) flag, so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC,QSA]
```